# Error al contar el número de elementos que tiene una lista

Tags: python

Tengo una tabla donde a modo de lista se han ido generando cada una de las compras que ha hecho cada vendedor en cada ocasión en la columna (Piezas_ordenes), además está asociado a cada fila con el vendedor que la realizó; en la columna (Venededor_ordenes):

```
['Cilindro de freno de rueda Eje trasero/ izquierda/ derecha', 'Cilindro de freno de rueda Eje trasero/ izquierda/ derecha']

['Cilindro de freno de rueda Eje trasero/ izquierda/ derecha', 'Cilindro de freno de rueda Eje trasero/ izquierda/ derecha', 'Cilindro de freno de rueda Eje trasero/ izquierda/ derecha']

['Cilindro de freno de rueda Eje trasero/ izquierda/ derecha']
```

Realizadas por dos vendedores diferentes

[JUAN] y [ER]

Me gustaría saber como contar el número de elementos que ha generado cada vendedor.
He intentado ejecutar la acción len para obtener quien es el empleado que más ventas ha hecho:

```
    for i in Ordenes.select():
    trabajador = str(i.Vendedor_ordenes)
    ventas = len(i.Piezas_ordenes)
    if trabajador in empleados:
        empleados[trabajador].append(ventas)
    else:
        empleados[trabajador] = [ventas]
     empleado_del_mes = {key: [sum(value)] for key, value in empleados.items()}
     inverse = [(value, key) for key, value in empleado_del_mes.items()]

print(inverse)
```

Me arroja este output:

```
                 [([124], 'ER'), ([248], 'JUAN')]
```

Esto corresponde al número de letras en vez de elementos que hay en la lista
Me gustaría saber como obtener el número de elementos que conforman la lista

Comment: No son tuplas, sino listas. En cualquier caso la función estándar `len()` puede aplicarse tanto a tuplas como a listas y te dice cuántos elementos tiene. Por tanto lo que buscas sería `len(i.Piezas_ordenes)` (en vez de `collections.Counter` que es para otra cosa, en concreto para generar un diccionario de contadores que te dice cuántas veces dentro de la lista se repite cada elemento, y que además estarías usando mal, al no recoger el resultado en una variable, y que el `print(collections)` no tiene sentido, pues `collections` es el nombre del módulo)

Comment: Has editado la pregunta y ya no plantea el mismo problema al que se refiere mi comentario (o las respuestas recibidas). Ahora el problema está relacionado con `max()` y te está diciendo que le estás pasando como parámetro una lista vacía. Revisa tu bucle a ver si realmente metes algo en el diccionario `empleados`. Usa `print()` para cada valor que añadas y así verlo en pantalla al ejecutar.

Comment: @abulafia, he ordenado el bucle y me funciona bien, pero me devuelve el valor de cada letra en vez de cada elemente. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí hay varias cosas que no me cuadran. Una es que dices "tupla" pero estas usando listas (La diferencia está en que las tuplas son inmutables y se usan "( )" y las listas son mutables y se usa "[ ]" aunque para lo que necesitas no importa mucho)

Otra es que estás intentando imprimir la librería `collections` y te aconsejaría que nunca utilizes los nombres reservados ni los nombres de librerías que ya existen o te dará error.

Por otro lado lo que haces con `collections.Counter(i.Piezas_ordenes)` es ejecutar la función Counter sobre el objeto `i` pero no guardas ese resultado en ninguna parte. Podrías usar esa lista `empleado_del_mes` que está sin usar.

Además de eso entiendo que el método `Piezas_ordenes` devuelve una única lista con varios elementos, asi que en realidad no es necesario la función `Counter` en este caso puesto que un simple `len(i.Piezas_ordenes)` te devolvería cuantos elementos tiene esa lista. Puesto que dices que has almacenado en las ordenes cada "fila" por empleado, entiendo que si los empleados no se repiten tendrán un orden (un índice). En ese caso puedes recorrer todas las listas y guardarlas en empleado_del_mes y despues usar la funcion `max()` junto con la función `index()` en la lista para que te devuelva qué posicion de esa lista es el numero más alto, tal que así `empleado_del_mes.index(max(empleado_del_mes)`. Si sabes en qué orden están las ventas, sabes qué empleado tiene más ventas con ese índice.

Eso tiene un "pero" y es que si resulta que dos empleados tienen el mismo numero de "ventas" te aparecerá solo un indice, pero para resolver eso lo dejo como ejercicio para el lector.

Espero que estos detalles te encaminen a lo que quieres lograr.

Un saludo

Comment: Hola @Jose he modificado la pregunta y he tenido en cuentra vuestros comentarios, pero sigo sin obtener el resultado que querría. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Las tuplas se definen con paréntesis:
tupla = ("uno", "dos", "tres")

Las listas se definen con corchetes:
lista =  ["uno", "dos", "tres"]

Los conjuntos se definen con llaves:
conjunto = {"uno", "dos", "tres"}

Los diccionarios se definen con llaves:
diccionario =  {1:"uno", 2:"dos", 3:"tres"}

Y en todos ellos se pueden preguntar por su longitud con len(nombre).

Las tuplas sirven para almacenar valores inmutables, las listas sin embargo se pueden modificar. Los conjuntos no tienen elementos repetidos. Los diccionarios almacenan parejas de datos llave/valor.

Comment: Grcias @Juan Enrique García Sancho , sin embargo eso no resuelve el error